# difference between action and live action

Tags: meaning, differences, meaning-in-context

In film genres I have seen and heard 2 words:

1) Action Movie

2) Live-Action Movie

What is difference between these 2 words? What live represent here?

Answer (score 7):

This is probably general reference, but this might be hard to understand for someone learning English. Even though the phrases are very similar, they mean entirely different things.

1) An *action movie* is a movie where most of the content involves things like fights, chases, and explosions. This tends to be a very popular type of movie like terminator or die hard.

2) A *live action movie* is a movie that is performed with real actors filmed with a camera, rather than being animated or being a cartoon. You would use this phrase when trying to point out that a movie is not animated.

The cartoon *Scooby Doo* has a [live-action movie.](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Scooby-Doo_poster.jpg)

Also, the movie *Who framed Roger Rabbit?* is an animated movie with a bunch of real actors in it. We say that the real people are live-action characters because they are filmed with a camera instead of animated.

When you're talking about TV, "live" means that what they are recording is going straight to your TV. This is **not** the meaning of live used  for live action movie. Live in the phrase "live action" does not mean much of anything, the phrase together is what is important.

Comment: I read at wikipedia, word: live-action pointing towards film: Avengers, while I think that have animation e.t.c. in it.

Comment: @Hafiz A live action movie can have lots of animation and special affects. Live action just means it is not a cartoon. If a show is "animated", it means that it is drawn by animators instead of filmed, not that it has special effects or some animation.

Comment: Ok so live-action have animation+action while action is real explosions and fight sequences e.t.c. ?

Comment: live action doesn't have to have animation. It can though. You are right about action.

Comment: if it will not have animation then how live-action movie will be different than action movie?

Comment: This is how I usually remember it, Hafix: a "live-action film" features primarily _live_ actors; roles are _acted_ by _live_ people. There may be animation or computer-generated imagery in a live-action film, but so long as there are live human beings playing main roles, then it is in all probability a live-action film. An "action movie" is a genre featuring lots of action. Compare and contrast with a _comedy movie_ or a _drama film_, for example.